# Is set theory with "homogeneous comprehension" (no set can contain both sets and atoms) consistent?

Tags: logic, set-theory, alternative-set-theories

Is this single-sorted set theory with sets and atoms consistent? An atom is an element of the domain that is not a set. The idea is that the elementhood predicate $\in$ is not constrained very much by the axioms when the right argument is an atom, and that this acts as a safety valve for defusing paradoxes.

I have a set theory with the following predicates:

$ S $, which determines whether something is a set, and $\in$, the elementhood relation.

$A$ meaning *atom* is an abbreviation for $\lnot S$.

Let $\forall x : S \mathop. \varphi$ abbreviate $\forall x \mathop. S(x) \to \varphi$ and likewise for other combinations of quantifiers and predicates.

I impose the constraint that no set can contain both sets and atoms. Let's call this the **axiom of homogeneity**.

$$ \lnot \exists x : S \mathop. (\exists a : S \mathop. \exists b : A \mathop. a \in x \land b \in x) $$

I also have a restricted **axiom of extensionality**.

$$ S(a) \land S(b) \implies [ a = b \iff (\forall x \mathop. x \in a \leftrightarrow x \in b) ]$$

; and I have a restricted form of **comprehension**. In the axiom schema below $\varphi$ is constrained to contain no occurrences of the predicates $S$ or $A$.

$$(\lnot \exists a : S \mathop. \exists b : A \mathop. \varphi(a) \land \varphi(b)) \implies (\exists x : S \mathop. \forall a \mathop. a \in x \leftrightarrow \varphi(a))   $$

---

So far, I've attempted to investigate this weird alternative set theory by throwing paradoxes at it that I've seen before. However, the comprehension restriction is so different from ZFC's and NF(U)'s that I'm stumped on how to prove its consistency relative  to one of these theories.

For convenience, I'll define set-builder notation $\{ x : \varphi(x) \}$ to be the empty set $\varnothing$ when $\varphi$ holds of at least one set and at least one atom.

No restrictions at all are imposed on the $\in$ relation when the right argument is an atom. The idea is that this flexibility is a *safety valve* to defang possible paradoxes.

For example, the Russell set is defined as follows: $R = \{x : x \not\in x\}$.

Suppose $R$ is non-empty.

$R$ holds of at least one set, since $\varnothing \not\in \varnothing$.

Therefore $R$ contains sets alone.

Suppose $R \in R$, then by the definition of $R$, $R \not\in R$.

Suppose $R \not\in R$, then by the definition of $R$, $R \in R$.

This is a contradiction, therefore $R$ does not contain sets alone.

If $R$ would contain both a set and an atom, then the Russell predicate would hold for at least one set and at least one atom.

This is a contradiction.

Therefore $R$ is empty.

Russell's paradox is then a proof that $x \not\in x$ holds for at least one atom $m$.

Let's consider the paradoxical set $A = \{ A : A \in A \to \varphi \}$.

This set is equivalent to $A = \{A : A \not\in A \lor \varphi \}$.

However, the first predicate holds for at least one set and at least one atom $m$, therefore $A$ is empty.

Comment: Didn't Russell/Whitehead have a theory that was more restrictive, like a sort of graded set theory in which a set that contained atom could only contain atoms, a set that contained sets of atoms could contain only those, etc.? I'm not recalling the name. Edit: a little more googling reveals I was thinking of their ramified theory of types.

Comment: Just to be clear: you allow $a\in b$ when $b$ is an atom?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes. $S$ and $A$ are predicates; they aren't different sorts. The idea behind an atom is that $\in$ is not strongly constrained when its right argument is an atom ... and also that atoms aren't extensional.

Comment: @jwimberley, Yes. The set theory New Foundations (and its variants) is what you get when you take the type theory notion of stratification and use it to constrain what instances of comprehension are allowed. I wanted to make something up that was similar to that but more semantic than syntactic in nature.

Comment: My suspicion is that if your theory says essentially nothing about the $\in$-behavior of atoms, then your comprehension axiom will be too weak. Can you give any example of using your comprehension axiom to prove that a non-empty set exists?

Comment: $\varnothing$ exists since it is the value of $\{ x : \bot\}$. $\{\varnothing\}$ exists since it is the value of $\{ x : \varnothing \in x \}$ ... Okay, I think I see your point ... there isn't a way that I can see to rule out the existence of atom that contains $\varnothing$ and would 
"invalidate" my set. Yeah ... I think this theory is too weak to do anything useful. Thanks.

Comment: Err, wait. I can prove the existence of an atom satisfying the Russell predicate, $m$ above. Since $\{ x : x = m \}$ is homogeneous, it does not refer to the empty set. I think can use this to build $m, \{m\}, \{\{m\}\}, \cdots$.

Comment: there is a typo in comprehension, it should be $\varphi(a)$ [not $\varphi(x)$].

Comment: The restriction of comprehension to formulas that don't contain $S$ seems to be illusory, since if you have enough axioms to create finite sets of sets, "$x$ is a set" should be equivalent to "$\{x,\{x\}\}$ exists".

Comment: @Troposphere, no $x$ still can be an atom, even if $\{x,\{x\}\}$ exists.

Comment: @Zuhair: I was assuming the OP intended to have an axiom saying that atoms don't have elements, even if the question doesn't state it explicitly -- though now I see that the beginning of the question says that was _not_ the intention ...

Comment: I don't think it's possible for $x$ to be an atom and for $\{x, \{x\}\}$ to exist. $\{x\}$ is always a set, so $\{x, \{x\}\}$ would be non-homogeneous and thus not exist. I think you can use this fact to make a version of Russell's paradox where the variable is restricted to be a set ... and thus prove that the system is inconsistent. I think. I haven't worked through the details yet.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet, why $\{x\}$ is always a set? Your Extensionality axiom is restricted to *sets*, so there is nothing to forbid having  two distinct singletons of $x$ one is a set and the other is an atom. Possibly every object in your theory can have a co-extensional copy that is an atom.

Comment: I was interpreting $\{x\}$ as an abbreviation for $\{a:a=x\}$. This names a set because it’s an instance of set-builder notation. There could be an atom that contains $x$ alone, true, $\{x\}$ doesn’t refer to it.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, let $\varphi(a)$ be $a \neq a$, then by comprehension there is an empty set, from extensionality this would be unique, denote it by $\varnothing$, then use the formula $a=\varnothing$ and we get the set $\{\varnothing\}$, one can easily construct upper sets by parameter substitution of sets or atoms.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet, yes but by then you cannot escape using $S$ by expression $\exists k. k=\{x,\{x\}\}$ since $\{\}$ is an abbreviation that uses $S$ in its open expansion, if you allow the use of $\{ \}$ in formulas of comprehension, then of course this would render your theory inconsistent easily.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet, I changed the biconditional into implication in comprehension because there is no need to stree the opposite direction, since it would clearly follow from homogeneityl

Answer (score 1):

As written the theory is clearly inconsistent.

Let $\varphi(x)$ be the formula $x=\emptyset$, where $\emptyset$ is the empty *set*, use it in comprhension, and we'll have: $x = \emptyset \iff x \neq \emptyset$.

If $\varphi(x)$ in comprehension is changed to  $\varphi(a)$ [as it should be], then I think we get a consistent but weak theory.